# AJAX or XHR request on iOS device failed with code 0 after server returns redirect (302)

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on a mobile application, that developed with Cordova (PhoneGap).
My base code is written in JavaScript, and it compiled into Native Android and iOS code.
In one of my requests to load XML, I send a request to UrlA, and the server **redirect (status 302)** the request to UrlB. Then a response with the XML returns from UrlB.

All this process works fin on Android devices (and on Desktop).

But on iOS devices, for some reason the request to UrlA failed with code 0.

I try to change my request form jQuery's Ajax into a Pure JS solution with XHR object. But the result was the same.

The original Ajax request (works on Android only)

```
$.ajax(
{
   type: "GET",
   url: xmlUrl,
   dataType: "xml",
   crossDomain: true,
   async: true,
   timeout: 7000, // 7sec before timeout failure
   beforeSend: function(xhr)
   {
      //xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");                                  

      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
   },

   // Request succeed
   success: successCallback,                                 
   // Request failed
   error: errorCallback
}
```

My 2nd attempt, with XHR request (works on Android only)

```
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (XHR)
{
   var method = 'GET';
   var isAsync = true;

   XHR.onreadystatechange = function()
   {
      switch (XHR.readyState)
      {
         case 0:
            console.log("# XHR: State 0 - Request isn't initialized");
            break;
         case 1:
            console.log("# XHR: State 1 - Request was set up");
            break;

         case 2:
            console.log("# XHR: State 2 - Request was sent");
            break;

         case 3:
            console.log("# XHR: State 3 - Request in progress");
            break;

         case 4:
            console.log("# XHR: State 4 - Request is completed");
            if (XHR.status == 200) // OK
            {
               console.log("# XHR: Request Success!");
               console.log(XHR);

               var responseText = XHR.responseText;
               var responseXml = XHR.responseXML;

               successCallback(responseXml)
            }
            else // request failed
            {
               console.warn("# XHR: Request Failed!");
               console.log(XHR);

               failerCallback("# XHR: Request failed! [Status: " + XHR.status + "]");
            }
            break;

            default:
               console.log("# XHR: Unknown ReadyState [" + XHR.readyState + "]");
               break;
      }
   };

   XHR.open(method, xmlUrl, isAsync);
   XHR.send(); // Start request
}
else
{
   failerCallback("XHR isn't defined");
}
```

I also notice that on Android devices when running the code with the XHR object we get all readyState (1 to 4, one after the outer)
But on iOS device we get only readyState 1, and the readyState 4 but with statusCode 0.

Comment: I have same problem. Anyone have solutions to solve

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
if (XHR.status == 200) // OK
```

with

```
if ((XHR.status >= 200 && XHR.status < 300) ||
   (XHR.status === 0 && !!XHR.responseXML))
```